# Undefined variable '$category'. when using queries

Tags: laravel

intelephense is giving me a syntax error in when writing this code, clearly $category was passed so what is the problem?

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)

{
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, function ($query, $search) {

        $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });



    $query->when(
        $filters['category'] ?? false,
        function ($query, $category) {
            $query
                ->whereExists(
                    function ($query) {
                        $query->from('categories')
                            ->whereColumn('categories.id', 'posts.category_id')
                            ->where('categories.slug', $category);
                    }
                );
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the necessary variables from the parent scope into the closure with the use keyword.

```
$query->when(
        $filters['category'] ?? false,
        function ($query, $category) {
            $query
                ->whereExists(
                    function ($query) use ($category) {
                        $query->from('categories')
                            ->whereColumn('categories.id', 'posts.category_id')
                            ->where('categories.slug', $category);
                    }
                );
        }
    );
```